# How To Block Mouse Click on Selected Area in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent

I'm beginner in python, I've looked through some posts about blocking mouse input but they discuss about freezing mouse entirely. What I want to know is how to block on just an area.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the clickEvent you first need to check that the click is outside the circle and then, if it's outside the circle, you execute the code.
Let's suppose for example that your circle has center in (2,2) and radius 1:
def example(event, x, y, flags, param):

```
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if (x -2)**2 + (y-2)**2 >= 1: #check you are outside circle
           #your code here
```

Comment: Like that it is already like that, if you click in the circle nothing happens. Because no code is executed if you click outside your code is executed, but the mouse is always able to move.

Comment: I added a code which is suitable for openCv. For external use you need to choose  the libraries you want to use. But the basic logic is that, you make a check after the mouse event happens.

Comment: No, i don't recommend OpenCV. But i recommend you to repost your question and be more precise as you have been in the last comment. From you're original question it was quite difficult to understand this.